# Smooch - Can a reply be sent to a user's email

Tags: smooch

Is there a way to tag a user's email (if a user is logged-in via our own AUTH) so Smooch can send a conversation reply to the user's email?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Smooch [Mailgun integration](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/mailgun/) you can send email over Smooch just like any other messaging channel. To attach an email address to an existing user in order to send them email messages, you can use the [link user to channel](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#link-app-user-to-channel) and supply a type of `mailgun`.

See also the [channel linking guide](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/linking-users/#for-mailgun) as well as the guide for [business initiated conversations](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/business-initiated-conversations/) for more information and examples.